# Run JVM's keytool programmatically as admin on Windows & Linux

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, keytool

I'm trying to make this work,
first I tried it with as follow:

```
sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(cmd);
```

but it doesn't work when trying to import certificate because it doesn't run as admin.

Any other ways to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: How can I simulate the following flow by code:
 On windows OS, right click on 'cmd' and do "run as admin" and it doesn't ask for password.

Comment: Why would you want to run the command line tool `keytool` programmatically? You have `KeyStore` api provided by Java to do the same keytool functionalities programmatically.

Comment: I've tried that but when I try to do 'import' it throws exception "access denied"

Comment: Do you have a code example for that?

Comment: Where is your keystore? If java doesn't have access to that location, you would get the same errors using the keytool and keystore. So you need to make sure java has access to that directory. If admin privileges are needed, you need to grant admin rights to java.

Comment: I'll give it a try.